# Instantiate collection without knowing concrete type

Tags: swift, generics, collections

I have a class which is generic over a type T which conforms to the Collection protocol. Now I want to instantiate the collection without knowing the concrete type of the collection, is this possible?

```
class FileStore<T: Collection>{

   var collection: T

   init(){
      collection = T() // This will never work
   }

}
```

Comment: I'm very curious what problem this is solving. What would you then do with `collection` that doesn't care whether it's ordered or unique, and doesn't care what the Element type is?

Comment: Also, since the resulting collection is not promised to be mutable, how would you use this?

Comment: Rob im trying to make a flexible fileStore. I want to be able so serialise any collection and save it to file and retrieve it again... the collection var is for "caching" the data will be persisted when the app goes into background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collection` doesn't have `init` amongst its protocol requirements, so you cannot directly initialize a `Collection` instance. You have several solutions though. You can either restrict your generic type constraint to a type that does guarantee having an init (such as `Array`) or you can create your own protocol requiring `init`, make `T` require conformance to that protocol and extend all `Collection`s that you want to be able to store to conform to your protocol.

The second approach is shown below:

```
protocol Initializable {
    init()
}

class FileStore<T: Collection> where T: Initializable {
    var collection: T

    init(){
        collection = T.init()
    }
}

// Extend the `Collection` conformant types
extension Array: Initializable {}
extension Dictionary: Initializable {}
extension Set: Initializable {}

// Create a FileStore
FileStore<Array<Int>>()
FileStore<[String:Int]>()
FileStore<Set<String>>()
```

Or depending on which exact types you want to be able to store, using the built-in `RangeReplaceableCollection` as your type constraint is even better. (Bear in mind that quite a few standard library types don't conform to `RangeReplaceableCollection` that do conform to `Collection` and have empty inits, such as `Dictionary`, `Set`, etc.).

```
class OtherFileStore<T: RangeReplaceableCollection> {
    var collection = T.init()
}
```

Comment: Rather than `T: Initializable`, I would suggest `T: RangeReplaceableCollection`. It gives the same benefit, but has proper semantics, and happens to be built-in. "Initializable" doesn't tell you anything about the resulting collection (it may not even be valid). RangeReplaceableCollection requires that the resulting collection be empty.

Comment: In order to include `Set`, you will also need to provide a version for `: SetAlgebra`, which provides the same "init promises empty" semantics. For more on the semantics issue I'm describing, see https://oleb.net/blog/2016/12/protocols-have-semantics/

Comment: @RobNapier thanks for the information, I didn't realize `RangeReplaceableCollection` had an `init` :) However, that does pose a more strict type restriction than a custom protocol. Could you please elaborate on _"Initializable doesn't tell you anything about the resulting collection (it may not even be valid)."_? I'm not sure how can a collection type that has an init with no arguments be invalid?

Comment: The point is that nothing in `Initializable` promises that the result is a useful or valid value (this is independent of being "a collection" which is not required by the protocol). It just says "it has an init()." For example, `NSError` has an `init()`, but the resulting value is invalid. And there's certainly no promise that the resulting collection is empty. This particular case is also weird because it doesn't require mutability, so I'm not sure how it would even work.

Comment: @RobNapier in general you're right about `Initializable`, but since the type constraint here is `Collection && Initializable`, I don't see an issue of how an invalid value could be initialized. Since the `Collection` conformant types need to be extended to also conform to `Initializable`, OP can make sure that only types whose `init` guarantees an empty collection get extended, but I do see your point that it requires some further developer attention, the compiler cannot give you all the semantic guarantees that you'd need.

Comment: Lot of very useful info here! Thanks a lot! Basically I just wanted to know just "how flexible" I could make this thing. I ended up making it generic over <K, V> instead which suffice what I need right now, but at some point I might want to use this thing to store something like an array which then will not be possible...